# How can I compile php-cgi binary using a custom glibc for suse enterprise linux out of cygwin?

Tags: linux, compilation, glibc

Pretty straight to the point I think. Is this do-able?

Background: I'm doing this because I need to run php-cgi on suse enterprise 9 and can't get LD_PRELOAD or LD_LIBRARY_PATH to use other-than-system version of glibc.

```
php-cgi: /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found
```

I downloaded 2.7 from here

http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)

more precisely

ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/sourceforge/r/ro/roblinux/64-32_pkg/core/i686/glibc-2.7-2rt.i686.rpm

and unpacked it using rpm2cpio.

I need php-cgi because I can't install php and want to try JavaBridge for running php out of tomcat.

Comment: Can't help you, but I have to say this makes about as much sense as trying to steal a tank from the local army base when your car won't start in the morning.

Comment: Wait, where does cygwin come into the picture? I am confused.

Comment: Cygwin is my trusty swiss army pocket knife. I develop on Windows XP and use Cygwin for everything nix related. I don't have root access to the Linux server. Tyler - the car won't start because the engine is missing. I have 2 choices - build my own engine or steal a tank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I compile php-cgi binary using a custom glibc for suse enterprise linux out of cygwin?
>
> Pretty straight to the point I think.

No, a *very* confused and circuitous question.

First, cygwin has *absolutely nothing* to do with your question: it's for running UNIX programs on Windows, which is *not at all* what you are asking about.

Second, your question appears to be: "how do I run pre-build php-cgi binary on a system that has older glibc than the one php-cgi has been built on?", and not about *compiling* anything.

To *that* question, the answer is: you can't (easily) -- UNIX systems do not support forward binary compatibility (build on a new system, run on an older one). Only backward compatibility is supported (old dynamically-linked binaries continue to run on newer systems).

Your best approach is to try to build php-cgi on your system (which would eliminate its dependency on `GLIBC_2.7`. If you can't, you should still be able to run such a binary against unpacked glibc-2.7 build, *if* that binary doesn't re-exec itself. The way to do that, assuming you unpacked glibc-2.7 into e.g. `/tmp/glibc-2.7` is something like:

```
/tmp/glibc-2.7/lib/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path \
    /tmp/glibc-2.7/lib:/lib:/usr/lib \
  /path/to/php-cgi <args>
```

(The library path above may need some adjustments to make the loader find all the required libraries.)

Update:

> is it practical to compile stuff for my linux box in cygwin

It *is* possible, but *significantly* more pain then simply compiling on the linux box itself (and so isn't really practical). You appear to lack any reason to want to do that, other than mis-guided belief that cygwin solves *all* problems.

Comment: It was more along the lines of, is it practical to compile stuff for my linux box in cygwin? Then I gave background in case someone may have a suggestion for me. I will try loading custom glibc your way.